# AngularJS - filter has no value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

**1. This is my supportDoc $scope:**

```
var supportDoc = this;
......
supportDoc.docs = data;
```

[image]

**2. My ng-repeat:**

```
data-ng-repeat="doc in supportDoc.docs | $uniqueFilter: doc.icon"
```

**3. And my filter:**

```
/*@ngInject */
$uniqueFilter.$inject = [];
ng.module('app.Shared.Layout').filter('$uniqueFilter', $uniqueFilter);
function $uniqueFilter(input, key) {
    var unique = {};
    var uniqueList = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (typeof unique[input[i][key]] == "undefined") {
            unique[input[i][key]] = "";
            uniqueList.push(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return uniqueList;
     };
```

My filter is being reached but no matter what combination I use, eg.

```
| $uniqueFilter: icon
| $uniqueFilter: doc.icon
| $uniqueFilter: supportDoc.docs.icon
```

etc., I still receive the same error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.$uniqueFilter (http://localhost:3250/app/dashboards/_shared/layout/filters/unique.client.filter.js:10:34)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:36:315)
    at Object.$get (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:34:268)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:36:315)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:38:110
    at Object.d [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:36:13)
    at $get [as $filter] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:140:92)
    at ib.filter (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:193:186)
    at ib.filterChain (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:193:136)
    at ib.statements (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js:192:441)

```
    <!-- ngRepeat: doc in supportDoc.docs | $uniqueFilter: icon
```

The data is there. Removing the filter allows the data to be displayed property, albeit with duplicates that the filter was meant to be used to remove.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace please ?

Comment: First, the use of the filter is the first --> `| $uniqueFilter: icon`. You can forget the others

Comment: I tried that, it did not work.

Comment: Excuse me I am wrong ! It must it the model, so, the third : `supportDoc.docs.icon`

Comment: If you read above, I tried all three combinations, the parameter value in the filter is always 'undefined'.

Comment: You should typically not use `$name` syntax since `$---` usually signifies angular's internal methods/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter function should return another function.

`module.filter('$uniqueFilter', function () {
   return $uniqueFilter;
})`

Documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like angular.forEach to avoid the error.

```
angular.forEach(input,function(row){
    if (typeof unique[row[key]] == "undefined") {
        unique[row[key]] = "";
        uniqueList.push(row);
    }
});
```

and try this :

```
ngRepeat: doc in supportDoc.docs | $uniqueFilter: 'icon'
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned Vinay K, your filter as to look at that :

```
/*@ngInject */
$uniqueFilter.$inject = [];
ng.module('app.Shared.Layout').filter('$uniqueFilter', $uniqueFilter);

function $uniqueFilter() {

    return function(input, key) {
        var unique = {};
        var uniqueList = [];
        angular.forEach(input,function(row){
            if (typeof unique[row[key]] == "undefined") {
                unique[row[key]] = "";
                uniqueList.push(row);
            }
        });
        return uniqueList;
    }
}
```